# Permalink Settings

Tags: permalinks

I have a `.htaccess` problem what buggs me out for couple of hours already. I have updated the file as it should be:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /zootaxi.lv/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /zootaxi.lv/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

and Im working on localhost.

I've tried both paths:

```
C:\wamp\www\zootaxi.lv
```

and

```
C:\wamp\www\zootaxi.lv\wp-content\themes\zootaxi
```

Advice much appreciated,

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "I've tried both paths..."? Where do you input them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mod_rewrite`is probably not activated on your localhost that why permalink can't work.
Just uncomment this line in apache :

```
#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```